# give div image title

Tags: javascript, html

is it possible to give a div an Id from image title within. so that any image that is uploaded into an empty div without an id the div.id will copy the images title
using js

example pass OSCAR up to div id

```
<div id="">
<img src="images/image/image.png" title="OSCAR"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Short answer, yes. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jQuery and use this code for set div id:

```
$(function(){
  $("div > img[title]").each(function(){
   var parent = this.parentNode;
   if(!parent.id)parent.id=this.title;//if id is empty, set id from title
 })
})
```

Or you can take div so:

```
$("img[title='OSCAR']").parent("div");
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering this question is not tagged `jQuery` and all `img` should have a `title` attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/eC3DE/

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('div > img'),
    i = 0,
    len = images.length,
    img;

for (; i < len; i++) {
    img = images[i];
    img.parentNode.id = img.title;
}
```

*Please note that you will have to run the code everytime an image is added to the `DOM`. If you are using a modern browser that supports the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) object, you could use it to detect when new images are added.*